# React Native - Animate width shrink

Tags: javascript, react-native, animation, transition

In the header of my React Native app, I have a conditional icon and a [Searchbar](https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html).

```
static navigationOptions = ({ navigation }) => {
const { params = {} } = navigation.state;
return {
  headerTitle: (
    <View
      style={{
        flex: 1,
        backgroundColor: Platform.OS === 'ios' ? '#e54b4d' : '',
        alignItems: 'center',
        flexDirection: 'row',
        paddingHorizontal: 10,
        height: StatusBar.currentHeight,
      }}>
      {params.isIconTriggered && <Icon name="chevron-left" size={28} />}
      <SearchBar
        round
        platform={'default'}
        placeholder="Search"
        containerStyle={{
          flex: 1,
          backgroundColor: 'transparent',
        }}
      />
    </View>
  ),
  headerStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#e54b4d',
  },
};
};
```

Normally the Searchbar will take the full width of the header which is what I want. If the condition `isIconTriggered` is true, an icon will appear in front of the Searchbar and the width of the SearchBar will shrink enough so that the icon is visible next to it.

However, there is no transition or animation when this happens and it does not feel nor look nice. I would like to add an animation to the Searchbar so the width shrinks gradually and smoothly when the condition is triggered and the icon appears.

Is that possible to achieve and how can I achieve this?

Comment: Are you using any style library like `styled-components`?

Comment: @SergioEscudero I do not use any styling libraries.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Try to learn Animated API of react native.

Here is how i done it with button trigger.

[image: here is the preview]

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {StyleSheet, View, TextInput , Button, SafeAreaView, Animated} from 'react-native';
import FA from 'react-native-vector-icons/FontAwesome5'

const AnimatedIcon = Animated.createAnimatedComponent(FA)
// make your icon animatable using createAnimatedComponent method

export default class Application extends Component {

  animVal = new Animated.Value(0);
   // initialize animated value to use for animation, whereas initial value is zero

  interpolateIcon = this.animVal.interpolate({inputRange:[0,1], outputRange:[0,1]})
  interpolateBar = this.animVal.interpolate({inputRange:[0,1],outputRange:['100%','90%']})
  // initialize interpolation to control the output value that will be passed on styles
  // since we will animate both search bar and icon. we need to initialize both 
  // on icon we will animate the scale whereas outputRange starts at 0 end in 1
  // on search bar we will animate width. whereas outputRange starts at 100% end in 90%

  animatedTransition = Animated.spring(this.animVal,{toValue:1})
  // we use spring to make the animation bouncy . and it will animate to Value 1

  clickAnimate = () => {
    this.animatedTransition.start()
  }
  // button trigger for animation

  //Components that will use on Animation must be Animated eg. Animted.View
  render() {
    return (
      <SafeAreaView>
      <View style={styles.container}>
        <View style={styles.search}>
        {/* our icon */}

        <Animated.View style={{width: this.interpolateBar}}>
        <TextInput placeholder='search here' style={styles.input}/>
        </Animated.View>

        <AnimatedIcon name='search' size={28} style={{paddingLeft: 10,paddingRight:10, transform:[{scale: this.interpolateIcon}]}}/>
        </View>

          <Button title='animate icon' onPress={this.clickAnimate}/>
      </View>
      </SafeAreaView>
    );
  }
}

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  container: {
    backgroundColor:'#F79D42',
    // flex: 1,
    height:'100%',
    paddingTop:20,
    flexDirection: 'column',
    // justifyContent: 'center',
    alignItems:'center'
  },
  input:{
    width: '100%',
    height:40,
    backgroundColor:'gray',
    textAlign:'center'
  },
  search:{
    flexDirection:'row-reverse',
    width:'90%',
    height:40,
    alignItems:'center'
  }
});
```

Solution using react-native-elements SearchBar component.
Wrapped the SearchBar Component inside Animated.View.
to explicitly animate the search bar

Like This:

```
 <Animated.View style={{width: this.interpolateBar}}>
    <SearchBar
    placeholder="Type Here..."
    containerStyle={{width: '100%'}}
  />
    </Animated.View>
```

[image]

Comment: Wow. Thank you for all the time and effort put into this answer. I think this could be the solution I need, however I cannot get it to work. The SearchBar (https://react-native-training.github.io/react-native-elements/docs/searchbar.html) I am using needs `flex: 1` in order to display fully and work properly, I guess it might be buggy or something. Having this messes up everything and the animation will not work. Can you maybe try to use the SearchBar from React-Native-Elements in your example? I have really been struggling with it all night and no success so far.

Comment: I haven't tried react-native-elements library yet. can you use width/height property instead of flex?

Comment: I tried using both `height` and `width`. However, it did not work.

Comment: if that is the case. the solution i can only think of is to wrap the searchbar component inside Animated.View. so it can explicitly animate without modifying the properties of searchbar component. i update my answer

Comment: I found this after I've implemented something that works exactly like that, but for me, the animation is quite laggy because I we can not use the native driver for layout props. How did you get it to be so fluid?

Comment: @Sami I see no mention of useNativeDriver in this example so I'd assume it's fluid because the JS-thread isn't busy in that minimal example. I have found that you can get the native driver to drive layout animations with LayoutAnimation (https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/layoutanimation). If globally animating everything isn't your style you might also look at the new Transitions API in Reanimated.

Comment: Yes, that is the answer, I guess. I have tried using LayoutAnimations, but there are issues with dismissing the Keyboard and using Layout Animations, otherwise it would have been perfect :)
I will start looking into the reanimated library. We're using it for another library anyway and using reanimated for animations seems to be in every way superior.

Answer (score 1):

You can achieve this using [Animated](https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/animated) API of React Native.

You can check this [tutorial](https://moduscreate.com/blog/expanding-and-collapsing-elements-using-animations-in-react-native/) for an overview of changing the size of elements with animation.

Answer (score -1):

React-Native-Animatable is super cool!
Try this one out:

1. Create A custom animation object

```
import * as Animatable from 'react-native-animatable';

Animatable.initializeRegistryWithDefinitions({
   const myAnimation = {
      from: {
          width: 200 
      },
      to: {
          width: 100
      }
   }
})
```

2. Use is as Animation value within a view or as a reference within a function call.

   Within a view:

```
   <Animatable.View useNativeDriver animation={myAnimation}/>
```

3. As a reference variable:

```
   <Animatable.View useNativeDriver ref={ref=>(this.testAnimation = ref)}/>
```

Method:

```
   testMethod = () => {
       this.testAnimation.myAnimation();
   }
```